# Generating a Delegated Access Token in C# asp.net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bearer-token

I am trying to generate a Delegated Access token(Bearer Token) for graph.microsoft.com in C# asp.net core 3.0. I managed to get a normal application token but it requires a Delegated token.

```
    private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        string clientId = "your_clientid";
        string clientSecret = "your_clientsecretid";
        string tenantId = "your_tenantid";

        var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
            .Build();

        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();

        return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
```

Comment: .NET Core 3.x has reached End-of-Life. The oldest supported version is .NET 6.0, a Long Term Support version supported until November 2024. Do you really want to start a project with a dead runtime that's probably not supported by the current Graph NuGet packages?

Comment: I am well into the project. I need to this to be able to send an email. If it is possible then I would like to know how I can go about getting the Delegated Access Token please.